# why there's no changes in my syntax highlighting?

Tags: vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting

I tried to syntax highlighting my newly planned language but it doesn't seem to goes well. I successes to make it colorful once before, but then the progresses was gone, probably because I clicked don't save when closing. I tried to do the things all over again but this time when I press F5 and open the file with same suffix to test it out, nothing was highlighted even the simplest one. This is the simplest one I got left, where could be the problem for not highlighting anything?

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "scopeName": "source.pfc",
    "name": "pfc",
    "patterns": [
        { "include": "#chart" }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "chart": {
            "name": "storage.type.function.js",
            "match": "\\b(chart)\\b"
        }
    }
}
```

in the file I created for testing, there's a "chart" text at the top (the first word in the file), but like I said, nothing was highlighted